# JavascriptExecutor (used in Selenium - Java) not working as intended for FF 24.0

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used the following command in few of my test cases, because this command is most helpfull if your trying to click on a hidden element (which appears only when hovered on some context)..

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('selector_for_element').click();");
```

it was working fine when tested on FF 15.0, now if i try the same on FF 24.0, getting the following error **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: waiting for evaluate.js load failed**

any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As far as i know, supports is there till Firefox 23. Correct me if i am wrong. You can see the changelog [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG)

Comment: Tried in 23.0 as well, its giving the same error

Comment: Are you using the latest selenium jar file 2.35 ?

Comment: as per [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6051) issue, i am able to see that, upgrading to latest version solved their issue. you can download latest selenium jar from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: i'l try that and get back to u

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked..can you please type the solution as your answer,so that i can accept it...might help others in future:)

Comment: Welcome ! Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6051) issue, i am able to see that, upgrading to latest version solved their issue. you can download latest selenium jar from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)